# How do you set the rancher project for a namespace in kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I'd like to create a namespace in the default project with a yaml-file in rancher via kubectl. Is this possible by using a label/annotation/etc. or do you have any other way aside the REST-API?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answere thanks to ChatGPT-3

```yaml
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Namespace
    metadata:
      name: namespace-name
      annotations:
        field.cattle.io/projectId: cluster-id:project-id
```

Comment: [ChatGPT answers are strictly prohibited.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)

Comment: "Thanks too" is different from a Chat-GPT written answer. I asked, got an answer, and posted what finally worked for me as a reminder and hint for others.